# PHP: ejecucion de scripts php con usuarios comunes

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-cli

Necesitaría saber qué tengo que cambiar en la configuración de mi php.ini (CLI) (o donde haga falta) para permitir que un usuario común pueda ejecutar un script escrito en php.

Cuando lo ejecuto como root no tengo problemas, cuando lo ejecuto como usuario comun obtengo el error:

> Could not open input file: xx.php

La solución de agregar al usuario en sudoers no es viable...
Estoy usando Ubuntu 14.04 LTS con PHP 5.5.9-1
Gracias.

Comment: Creo yo que va más por el lado de que los archivos son creados como root y solo root los puede abrir, tendrias que cambiar los permisos de tus archivos para que cualquier usuario lo pueda ver y utilizar.

Comment: Lo resolví (temporalmente) asignando como dueño del script al usuario. Parece que con permiso de lectura y de ejecución no alcanza. Es algo de la versión de Ubuntu. En otra instalación con versión 12 funciona sin problemas. Lo que "molesta" es que tengo que crear una copia del script para cada usuario que tenga que ejecutarlo...

Comment: No se como tengas tu estructura de tus archivos pero deberias probar con darle todos los permisos a tu carpeta donde tengas todos tus archivos php con nombre_carpeta chmod 777